# Windows 10 universal app - Run in fullscreen mode by default

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have application with target windows 8.1 and when I run this application on Windows 10, it is run in small window by default.

Because it is primary tablet application I need it to run in full-screen mode by default. Is it possible to set it somewhere in Visual Studio or in some config of the application?

Comment: The porting guide [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188204.aspx).  I assume you are looking for the section way at the bottom, as good as it gets.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To launch application in full screen mode, try setting `ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode` as early as in `App.xaml.cs`'s constructor

```
public App()
{
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

To have a button that toggles the full screen mode, do

```
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
if (view.IsFullScreenMode)
{
    view.ExitFullScreenMode();
}
else
{
    view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
}
```

However, I need to add that even without specifying any of the code above, when you open your app inside a Windows 10 tablet or a Windows 10 desktop with *Tablet Mode* enabled, the app will automatically maximise itself to full screen.

As long as your app is available on Windows 10 Desktop devices, I would recommend you **not** to set it to full screen at start-up 'cause UX wise it's a lot easier for desktop users to work with windowed applications.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But did you mean store application. Because your code is not available in windows store universal app. http://prntscr.com/8hv4mh

Comment: Now I see, this code is available only in Windows 10 universal app. I'm trying this in windows 8.1 app

Comment: Make sure to add 'using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;' to the top off your App.xaml.cs

Answer (score 4):

And in C++ :

```
Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView::PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = 
Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationViewWindowingMode::FullScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
this.InitializeComponent();
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(new Size(1360, 768));
```