# How can I prevent my UWP app from being displayed fullscreen?

Tags: uwp, resize, visual-studio-2019, fullscreen

In connection with my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995348/why-is-the-form-page-in-my-uwp-app-truncated-at-run-time-doesnt-reflect-desi), and in an effort to maximize my app's form/page, I used the code recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758775/windows-10-universal-app-run-in-fullscreen-mode-by-default):

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
}
```

(the third/final line is what I added).

This worked - the app went full-screen:

[image]

...but then I could only get it out of the way (access any other app) by selecting "Hot Reload" and then in Visual Studio "Stop Debugging."

So I commented out that line, yet the app still displays fullscreen.

I don't really want fullScreen; I want Maximized. So I uncommented that line of code, and changed the last part of it so that it is now this:

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.Maximized;
```

But it still displays fullscreen, rather than maximized.

How can I get it to stop displaying fullscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use the following code on the main page of your app to make your screen maximized:

```
        var DisplayView = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

        var resolution = new Size(DisplayView.ScreenWidthInRawPixels, DisplayView.ScreenHeightInRawPixels);

        // Calculate the screen size in effective pixels. 
        var scale = DisplayView.ResolutionScale == ResolutionScale.Invalid ? 1 : DisplayView.RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
        var ViewBounds = new Size(resolution.Width / scale, resolution.Height / scale);

        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(ViewBounds.Width, ViewBounds.Height);
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```

Please note that the Maximized window will work when you launch the app for the seconde time. This is mentioned here: [ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode?view=winrt-19041)